# VSCode PowerShell Extension failed to initialize

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, config

I'm just trying to activate my python virtual environment with Activate.ps1 but I'm getting the error
"PowerShell Editor Service client: couldn't create connection to Server.

I've tried to reinstall VSCode several times and cleared all the cache but nothing...
Any ideas?

[image]

This is the error I'm getting

```
[Warn  - 2:20:50 pm] OmniSharp.Extensions.LanguageServer.Server.LspServerOutputFilter: Tried to send request or notification before initialization was completed and will be sent later OmniSharp.Extensions.JsonRpc.RequestCancelled | @Request='OmniSharp.Extensions.JsonRpc.RequestCancelled'
[Error - 2:21:26 pm] Connection to PowerShell Editor Services (the Extension Terminal) was closed. See below prompt to restart!
[Error - 2:21:26 pm] Server initialization failed.
  Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097 
[Error - 2:21:26 pm] PowerShell Editor Services client: couldn't create connection to server.
  Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097 
[Error - 2:21:26 pm] Sending request powerShell/getCommand failed.
  Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the Execution Policy is not set to Restricted which means you won't be able to run any scripts with this settings.

To see the current execution Policy status run the command from powershell - `Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser` if the output is `Restricted` change it to `Unrestricted` with the command `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force`

*Note: `-Scope CurrentUser` Setting the scope to "CurrentUser" applies the execution policy change to the current user only. It overrides any machine-level execution policy settings for the current user. There are several `Scope` options below:*

> Process: When you set the scope to "Process," it means that the execution policy change is applied only to the current PowerShell process or session. It does not affect the system-wide or user-wide execution policy settings. The change is temporary and limited to the current session.
>
> LocalMachine: The "LocalMachine" scope sets the execution policy for
> all users on the local machine. This means the change affects all user
> accounts on the current computer.
>
> CurrentUserCurrentUserHost: This scope is similar to "CurrentUser,"
> but it also affects the current user's PowerShell host. It overrides
> both machine-level and current user host-level execution policies for
> the current user and host.
>
> LocalMachineCurrentUser: This scope applies the execution policy
> change to all users on the local machine but only for the current user
> host. It overrides machine-level execution policies but keeps any user
> host-specific policies intact.
>
> LocalMachineLocalUser: The "LocalMachineLocalUser" scope sets the
> execution policy for the current user on the local machine but does
> not affect other user accounts or other hosts.
>
> UserPolicy: When using the "UserPolicy" scope, the execution policy is
> determined by Group Policy settings defined for the user. It prevents
> the user from changing the policy locally.
>
> MachinePolicy: The "MachinePolicy" scope sets the execution policy
> based on Group Policy settings defined for the computer. It prevents
> users from changing the policy locally.

Sometime Unrestricted is not a good practice, so instead of `Unrestricted` you can also one of the below:

> Restricted: This is the most restrictive execution policy. It prevents
> the execution of all scripts, including PowerShell scripts and scripts
> downloaded from the internet. Only individual commands are allowed to
> run.
>
> AllSigned: With this execution policy, PowerShell scripts can run, but
> they must be digitally signed by a trusted publisher. This policy
> allows scripts that you have created on the local machine or scripts
> signed by a trusted source to run.
>
> RemoteSigned: In this policy, PowerShell scripts downloaded from the
> internet must be signed by a trusted publisher. Locally created
> scripts can run without a digital signature.
>
> Unrestricted: This policy allows the execution of all scripts,
> including those downloaded from the internet, without any digital
> signature requirements. It poses a security risk as it can run
> unsigned and potentially malicious scripts.
>
> Bypass: This policy allows the execution of all scripts without any
> restrictions. It is typically used temporarily to bypass other
> execution policies, but it can introduce security risks.
>
> Undefined: This policy means no execution policy is set. It doesn't
> enforce any restrictions, but it might inherit the policy from a
> parent scope.
>
> MachinePolicy: This execution policy is defined by Group Policy at the
> machine level. It prevents users from changing the policy at their
> level.
>
> UserPolicy: Similar to MachinePolicy, this execution policy is defined
> by Group Policy at the user level and prevents users from changing the
> policy for their account.

Comment: what are the blockquotes quoting here? documentation? link please?

Comment: Haha no documentation. Used ChatGPT to generate the meaning of the different parameters and scope options

Answer (score -1):

I ended up reinstalling PowerShell and now it's running again

Comment: SO is pretty strict on what is considered an answer.  In future it would be better to post this sort of thing as a comment to the original question.